# Link multiple vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges, faces

I would like to connect multiple vertices.
In my example, I would like to connect (with edges and faces) the front vertices with the ones on the back.

I have the same numbers of vertices on each side.

[image]

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: you can do it with Ctrl E > Bridge Edge Loop, but it's probably going to be ugly between the corners vertices, it's going to give very stretched faces

Comment: Well I already tried that, I have a message error saying "Select at least 2 edge loops"

Comment: switch to edge select (not vertex select) and make sure that the 2 edge on the length are not selected

Comment: Ow ok thanks indeed that seems obvious. Well the result is quite random and it doesnt really connect each vertices on the front with each vertices on the back :/

Comment: maybe share your file so that we can test? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sure, I added it in my post.

Comment: not sure what you mean, is it not what you want? https://zupimages.net/up/20/47/iogw.jpg

Comment: Yes it is ! I mean, that way it supposed to describe a surface that fits with the object. Because when i select all those vertices and hit "F" to fill, the face i get is very strange.

Comment: I got what I show with Ctrl E > Bridge Edge Loops, you'll have the same thing with Ctrl F > Grid Fill as explained by Lemon

Comment: Indeed ! I accidentally selected the edge on the side the first time, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to edge select mode:

[image]

Select the top edge loop except the 2 edges on each side:

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

What it gives with your mesh:

[image]

There are better topologies than this one but it depends on what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

Select the loop and use grid fill:

[image]